# Changing like query in a rails_admin association

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-admin

I am using rails admin and have two simple models:

```
class Spot < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :user_spots
end

class UserSpot < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :spot
end

RailsAdmin.config do |config|
    config.model UserSpot do
        exclude_fields :id, :created_at, :updated_at
    end
end
```

when I am adding a new Spot in the admin area, it shows the dropdown list correctly,

[image: My field]

but when I start typing, it executes the following sql by default:

```
  Spot Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `spots`.* FROM `spots` WHERE ((LOWER(spots.name) LIKE '%n%') OR (LOWER(spots.about) LIKE '%n%') OR (LOWER(spots.hours) LIKE '%n%') OR (LOWER(spots.location) LIKE '%n%') OR (LOWER(spots.call_info) LIKE '%n%') OR (LOWER(spots.website) LIKE '%n%') OR (LOWER(spots.menu) LIKE '%n%'))  ORDER BY spots.id desc LIMIT 30
```

**I would like to search only for name. Is it possible?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the same as:

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  config.model UserSpot do
    exclude_fields :id, :created_at, :updated_at
    list do
      field :about do
        searchable false
      end

      field :hours do
        searchable false
      end

      # Like this mark false all the fields you don't want to 
      # search. By default all fields are searchable.
    end
  end
end
```

Check [this wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/List) for more information.

Comment: Hi, I want to increase the LIMIT 30 to 50, could you please advise how can I achieve that?